# Pearson Correlation in SAS

Tags: sas, correlation, collaborative-filtering, pearson

I have a set of data with observations (Joe, Dana, Mark,...) and their respective ratings for a movie ( Batman - 3 Stars, Deadpool - 4 Stars). When I use the proc Corr in SAS only give the correlation between movie and not observations. 
How do I find the correlation between the **observations** in SAS?

Comment: Most likely it's related to your data structure. Post a sample of your data and include what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SPEARMAN option to correlate qualitative data and specify variables to correlate by VAR.

```
PROC CORR DATA=marks SPEARMAN;
VAR names films ;
RUN;
```

What have you tried before?